# Edit JVM Arguments outside from CF Admin Panel - ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I made a change in JVM Arguments and now the application server won't start. Can I edit the JVM arguments manually outside from the CF administrator and if yes, how? If a "manuall override" is not possible how can I remove the last entry that I added to the JVM in order to be able to start my app server again?

P.S: I am on a Win-Server machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for the file `jvm.config` in the bin directory from where you start the server. It contains the JVM arguments to be set for the server.

Comment: Thank you for this.
I put in an invalid JVM argument from the Admin Panel and then I couldn't get the service back up.